# how to import the following function?

Tags: python-3.x, import

Hello I have the following dictionary, with keys and frecuencies:

```
dictFrec = {'22': 21, '25': 9, '47': 21, '1': 22, '28': 20, '21': 12, '10': 136, '12': 106, '17': 20, '19': 39, '33': 89, '31': 40, '48': 52, '30': 37, '37': 18, '41': 114, '36': 49, '42': 30, '7': 22, '8': 29, '18': 22, '4': 18, '14': 49, '38': 16, '34': 37, '6': 11, '2': 19, '44': 16, '35': 69, '26': 52, '39': 30, '27': 16, '40': 24, '0': 31, '3': 21, '32': 71, '5': 17, '23': 27, '24': 36, '20': 26, '46': 19, '11': 28, '29': 50, '13': 19, '9': 101, '49': 44, '15': 23, '43': 17, '45': 37, '16': 72}
```

I order to get the 5 lowest values I designed the following function in a class:

```
import operator

class getStrange:

    def getStrangeD(my_dict):
        strange=dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:5])
        return strange
```

The issue comes when I tried to import it as follows:

```
from tools import getStrange as G
newA = G.getStrangeD(dictFrec)
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 55, in <module>
    newA = G.getStrangeD(dictFrec)
AttributeError: module 'tools.getStrange' has no attribute 'getStrangeD'
```

So I would like to receive support about this, I am trying to have this function to make more clean my code, However I am not sure how to import this function and where is the issue, thanks for the support,

this new class was stored in a file as follows:

```
/tools$ ls
getStrange.py  __pycache__
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using a class. Your code would otherwise work just fine; you seem to be importing a different `tools` module perhaps? Check for the filename (`import tools; print(tools.__file__)`). Another possibility is that you did not restart your script and Python is still using a previous revision of the code.

Comment: What is the name of this file? Is it `tools.py` or perhaps its  `tools/getStrange.py`?

Comment: @tdelaney I added this information in the question

Comment: You have a module called `getStrange` with a class called `getStrange` inside.

Comment: @tdelaney, yes, is that the root of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems. First, `getStrangeD` is written as an instance method but doesn't include a `self` variable. Since it doesn't use instance data, you can define it as a static method instead. Second, since its a member of the class, you need to include the class name when you access it.

*tools/getStrange.py*

```
import operator

class getStrange:

    @staticmethod
    def getStrangeD(my_dict):
        strange=dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:5])
        return strange
```

Now to use it

```
>>> from tools import getStrange as G
>>> dictFrec = {'22': 21, '25': 9} # ....
>>> newA = G.getStrange.getStrangeD(dictFrec)
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the support, this was really helpful